# R Count like rows in a vector by columns in data frame

Tags: r

I have a large data frame ( 3 million unique rows x 3 columns).. I need to count each iteration of the data frame where all three columns appear together in a vector (20000 rows). The vector is a concatenation of many different variables. I have a solution, however it takes hours to run. Looking for advice to speed up the process. Example:

```
X1 = c("AAA","ABC","DFD")
X2 = c("123","231","432")
X3 = c("12A","4GJ","213")
x <- data.frame(X1,X2, X3)
y <- c("ABD - 122 - XYZ", "ABC - 231 - 4GJ", "FDD - 213 - FJ2 - djf", "372 - DHFN - SJSN - fjd")

library(data.table)

### My Current Solution

freq <- rep(NA, nrow(x))
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
freq[i] <- length(which(y %like% x[i,1] & y %like% x[i,2] & y %like% x[i,3]))
}

### Solution 2
myfunc <- function(x) {freq <- length(which(y %like% x[1] & y %like% x[2] & y %like% x[3]))}

freq <- apply(x[,c(1:3)], 1, myfunc)

### Returns following Vector for both solutions
> freq
[1] 0 1 0
```

Running this returns a vector "freq" with 1st row containing 1 after fucntion found all three rows in that row of the vector. However, running this with 3 million iterations over a vector of 200k is too slow. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. The concatenated second row of `x` `"ABC - 231 - 4GJ"` does not match any of the entries in `y`. So why is the frequency 1 for that row?

Comment: In my data frame. Row 2; X1= ABC, X2 = 231, X3 = 4GJ.. All three variables can be found in 1 concatenated row of "ABC - 231 - 4GJ".. Therefore count of vector Freq is 1 at Row 2.

Comment: I see; it would've been to good to clarify that you had made a mistake in your original post. I've posted a short one-line solution in base R, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` from the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

X1 = c("AAA","ABC","DFD")
X2 = c("123","231","432") 
X3 = c("12A","4GJ","213")

y <- data.frame(code = c("ABD - 122 - XYZ", "ABC - 231 - 4GJ - fjd", "FDD - 213 - FJ2", "372 - DHFN - SJSN"))


y %>% 
  filter(grepl(paste(X1, collapse="|"), code)) %>% 
  filter(grepl(paste(X2, collapse="|"), code)) %>% 
  filter(grepl(paste(X3, collapse="|"), code)) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your Patterns
X1 = c("AAA","ABC","DFD")
X2 = c("123","231","432")
X3 = c("12A","4GJ","213")
x <- data.frame(X1,X2, X3)
x$pattern <- paste(x$X1, x$X2, x$X3, sep=" - ")

#put all your strings into one string
i <- 20000
string <- c("ABD - 122 - XYZ", 
        "ABC - 231 - 4GJ - fjd", "fjd - ABC - 231 - 4GJ", 
        "FDD - 213 - FJ2", "AAA - 123 - 12A - A", "AAA - 123 - 12A - B", 
        "AAA - 123 - 12A - c", 
        "372 - DHFN - SJSN", paste0(LETTERS[runif(i, 1,26)], LETTERS[runif(i,   1,26)])
        )

string2 <- paste0(string, collapse = ",")

#function to check each pattern against the string
cnt <- Vectorize(function(x){
      length(grepRaw(x, string2, all =T, fixed = T))
      }, SIMPLIFY = T)


#the result
cnt(x$pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R one-liner making use of `strsplit` and `%in%`:

```
freq <- apply(x, 1, function(x) sum(sapply(strsplit(y, " - "), function(y) all(x %in% y))))
freq
#[1] 0 1 0
```

This also takes care of additional fields in `y`. As long as all entries in `x` are present in `y`, the count is increased.